# liquibase changelog - uris must be even

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, cmd, liquibase, changelog

I am trying to create my first liquibase changelog in a spring application. I execute liquibase with maven but it doesnt work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="tobias">
        <createTable tableName="Entwickler">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="webseite" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="gruendungsdatum" type="BIGINT"/>
        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="Publisher">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="webseite" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="gruendungsdatum" type="BIGINT"/>
        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="Spiel">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="publisher_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_publisher"
                             references="Publisher(id)"/>
            </column>

        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="Bilder">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="picture_kind" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="game_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_game"
                             references="Spiel(id)"/>
            </column>

        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="Spiel_Entwickler">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="entwickler_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_Entwickler"
                             references="Entwickler(id)"/>
            </column>
            <column name="game_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_Game"
                             references="Spiel(id)"/>
            </column>

        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="Language">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Language" type="varchar(50)"/>

        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="plattform">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="plattform" type="varchar(50)"/>

        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="Redaktion">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Redaktion" type="varchar(50)"/>

        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="Language_Spiel">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="spiel_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_spiel"
                             references="Spiel(id)"/>
            </column>
            <column name="language_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_language"
                             references="Language(id)"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Youtube" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="Beschreibung" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="Altersfreigabe" type="int"/>
        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="spiel_plattform">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="spiel_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_spiel"
                             references="Language_Spiel(id)"/>
            </column>
            <column name="plattform_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_plattform"
                             references="plattform(id)"/>
            </column>
            <column name="releasedate" type="bigint"/>
            <column name="releasedate_kind" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="shop" type="varchar(50)"/>
        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="Rating">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="redaktion_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_Rating"
                             references="Redaktion(id)"/>
            </column>
            <column name="plattform_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_plattform"
                             references="spiel_plattform(id)"/>
            </column>
            <column name="rating" type="bigint"/>


        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="Genre">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="genre" type="bigint"/>


        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="Rating">
            <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="game_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_Game"
                             references="Language_Spiel(id)"/>
            </column>
            <column name="genre_id" type="int">
                <constraints nullable="false"
                             foreignKeyName="fk_genre"
                             references="Genre(id)"/>
            </column>
            <column name="rating" type="bigint"/>


        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

I execute liquibase with maven. mvn liquibase:update.

After executing I get the error that I need to have an even count of uris in header for schema location:

```
C:\Users\Tobi\IdeaProjects\games>mvn liquibase:update
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building games 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.2:update (default-cli) @ games ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
[INFO]   File: liquibase/liquibase.properties
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/games
INFO 19.05.18 14:44: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
WARNING 19.05.18 14:44: liquibase: SchemaLocation: schemaLocation-Wert = 'http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www
.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquiba
se.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext ' muss eine gerade Anzahl an URIs
haben.
INFO 19.05.18 14:44: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.568 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-19T14:44:16+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/200M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.2:update (default-cli) on project games: Error setting u
p or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Error parsing line 7 column 52 of liquibase/changelogs/Gameinterface
-changelog-1.xml: SchemaLocation: schemaLocation-Wert = 'http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xm
l/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbc
hangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext ' muss eine gerade Anzahl an URIs haben. -> [Help 1
]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My problem is the stack trace says I need an even number of uris in schema location at line 7 position 52. But my header line is not at line 7 but in line 4. I have executed liquibase in the intelliJ Terminal and in the cmd.

Comment: You should all relevant data in your question rather than just linking it! Note that the links may become invalid in future, so the whole thread becomes useless then...

Comment: Please don't link to code. I just embedded your XML and log output into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In maven logs you have:

```
SchemaLocation: schemaLocation-Wert = 'http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd 
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext' muss eine gerade Anzahl an URIs haben.
```

So try using:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
```

What version of `liquibase` are you using?

Also, your changeSets should have `preconditions`, so they won't fail when you execute them with the existing database.

As such:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="tobias">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="Entwickler"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createTable tableName="Entwickler">
        <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="webseite" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="gruendungsdatum" type="BIGINT"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Also, table names should start with lower-case letters.

And try to make your `changeSets` atomic. One `changeSet` - one database change. Don't put creation of all tables into one `changeSet`.